# not able to take backup of sql server compact database

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I am trying to take backup of sql server compact database, I used this code but it is not working.

```
        var srv = new Server(@".\SQLEXPRESS");
        SaveFileDialog SD = new SaveFileDialog();
        SD.ShowDialog();
       Backup BkpDBase = new Backup();
        this.Cursor = this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        //this.dataGridView1.DataSource = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string fileName = SD.FileName;
            BkpDBase.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
            BkpDBase.Database = "TapeDatabase.sdf";
            BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(fileName, DeviceType.File);
            BkpDBase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
            BkpDBase.SqlBackup(srv);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: "it is not working." isn't diagnostic. Are you getting an error/exception? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: yes, error, that TapeManagement.sdf database not found

Comment: If you're using `.\SQLEXPRESS` , then you're working against SQL Server **Express** - ***not*** SQL Server CE ! The SMO library doesn't work with SQL Server CE as far as I know - it's only valid against the **server-based** editions of SQL Server (not the file-based SQL Server CE)

Comment: then wat should I do for SQL Server CE

Answer (score 2):

With SQL server compact, just use File.Copy